# Insert FlexBox into image frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I want to position sap.m.FlexBox control inside an image frame like [THIS ONE](http://propertyinventories.com/wp-content/themes/Blandes/images/ipad-frame.png) for instance.
The image is in another FlexBox control:

```
var oContainer3 = new sap.m.FlexBox({
    id: "container3",
    direction: "Column",
    width: "70%",
    items: [
        new sap.m.Image({
            id: "tabletImg",
            src: "content/img/tabletVideoFrame.png"
        })
    ]
});
```

I need to place the following control:

```
var oSelectedFieldsContainer = new sap.m.FlexBox({
    id: "selectedFieldsContainer",
    direction: "Column",
    items: [
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "This is a container for Selected Fields",
            textAlign: "Right",
            width: "100%",
            height: 100%
        })
    ]
});
```

inside the image frame's empty space.

I tried to do the following in `onAfterRendering()` function of the controller:

```
var imgPosition = $("#tabletImg").position();
$("#tabletImg").before("<div id='selectedFieldsDiv'></div>");
      oSelectedFieldsContainer.placeAt("selectedFieldsDiv");
      var x = imgPosition.left + 70;
      var y = imgPosition.top + 170;
 $("#selectedFieldsDiv").css({
      position: absolute,
      z-index: 5000,
      top:      y, 
      left:     x
 });
```

The problem is that the image's size and position change with the screen resolution, and the new div's position - doesn't, so the control is jumping all over the screen..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following css properties to the required container:

```
#container {
    border-image: url('../content/img/tabletVideoFrame.png') 175 110 175 110;
    border-width: 45px;
    width:550px;
    height: 600px;
};
```

Adding the image as border solved the problem for me.

If anyone has a better solution, you're welcome to share it.